# Create dataframe from a list using the df.merge function

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a set of .txt files that I need to read and import into a dataframe. Each file has the same structure (x and y columns; the x column is equal for each file). I select the files using the tkinter dialog box and I get a tuple (filenames) with the path of each file that I need to read and import. My strategy is to read the files and store the data in the list data using a for loop.

```
data = []
for i in range(len(filenames)):
    df = pd.read_csv(filenames[i], delimiter = "\t")
    data.append(df)
```

(In this particular case `len(data)= 4`)Then with another for loop I am trying to convert the data list into a pandas dataframe using the command df.merge:

```
df_mrg = data[0]

for k in range(len(data)):
    df2 = data[k]
    df_mrg.merge(df2)
```

but it doesn't work and I only get a dataframe with 2 columns corresponding to data[0]
I also tryed to define a global variable inside the for loop and it's slighly better but still don't get all the data that I need:

```
df_mrg = data[0]

for k in range(len(data)):
    global a
    df2 = data[k]
    a = df_mrg.merge(df2)
```

Can anyone identify the mistake in my code or suggest a better strategy?

Python version: 3.8.3 using jupiter notebook
OS: windows 10

Comment: You have to assign the result of a merge back to itself. Try:  `df_mrg = df_mrg.merge(df2)`

Comment: You are definitely right!!! I spent I don't know how many hours in an attempt to understand it. It worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function does not update in place.  It returns a new datafame where if you want to accumulate the result, you need to assign the returned dataframe back to the original dataframe name.  Hence, you should use the following code inside the loop:

```
df_mrg = df_mrg.merge(df2)
```